# Why doesn't the MaxLength property on a RichTextBox work in WPF?

Tags: wpf, properties

I am trying to set the `MaxLength` property on a `RichTextBox` but it does not seem to work.

Any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that the WPF RichTextBox doesn't have a MaxLength property - unlike the Windows.Forms one.

Here's an improvement on @jhony's anwser. If you catch the PreviewKeyDown event and check the length, you also need to allow the user to press Delete and BackSpace after hitting the limit.

```
    // In constructor
    this.RichTextBox.PreviewKeyDown += this.EditBox_KeyDown;

    private void EditBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key != Key.Delete && e.Key != Key.Back)
        {
            var range = new TextRange(this.RichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, this.RichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
            if (range.Text.Length > this.MaxLength)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

You should also allow the arrow keys, because you wouldn't expect them to be disabled.

To disable pasting, put this in the constructor `DataObject.AddPastingHandler(this.RichTextBox, this.EditBox_Paste);` and

```
    private void EditBox_Paste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CancelCommand();
    }
```

However, you might want to allow pasting unless it breaks the MaxLength, in which case you'll need to check the text being inserted, and the text it is replacing. At that point I decided not to implement a MaxLength in the control, but to handle it with the rest of the validation in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in yout KeyDown Event.

```
private void rLetter_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
       TextRange tr= new TextRange(rLetter.Document.ContentStart,                                                   rLetter.Document.ContentEnd);
       if (tr.Text.Length > 4000 || e.Key == Key.Space || e.Key == Key.Enter)
       {
           e.Handled = true;
           return;
       }
}
```

I have some problem, The bug is :

> Test this code using copy and paste text max 4000.

Sorry for my English ..

Comment: If you have a separate problem, you need to post it as a separate question.

Comment: @DanPuzey This answer only half addresses the issue. His problem is the fact that it still doesn't prevent pasting. So this isn't a separate question.